# in that problem why didn't we simply put F2=800 and the angle=60 and the body will also keep moving horizontally

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

[image]

in that problem why didn't we simply put F2=800 and the angle=60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that solution would not yield the minimum $\boldsymbol{F}_2$ magnitude.

We know that the vertical component of $\boldsymbol{F}_2$ must equal $ \| \boldsymbol{F}_1 \| \sin( 60 )$ always to balance out the vertical forces.

The ideal solution would be the angle that provides *zero* horizontal component of $\boldsymbol{F}_2$ and thus minimum magnitude.